# Running a job/asynchronous task with spring 3 at frequency that can be altered by the user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I can set a task to run using scheduled annotation with a fixed frequency. However I want the frequency to vary depending on user input.

What is the best way to accomplish this  ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [TaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) directly without @Scheduled annotations.
You can schedule jobs using user input and have better control over task execution.

Declare you scheduler in spring context:

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="5" />
```

And inject it into your service beans using @Autowire annotation

```
@Autowire
private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
```

Comment: How would I initialize and then alter the frequency ?

Comment: spring will initialize it for you, all you need to do is to call one of the methods it provides